# What's the differences between "Will" and "Would" as present tense?

Tags: will-would

I always appreciate all the people here. Today I have a question about will-would usage. I know there're lots of answers for them already. However I just need to learn them with my sentences for better understanding.

< Will >

> A : You'll die for them?
>
> B : Yes, I will!

---

< Would >

> A : You'd die for them?
>
> B : Yes, I would!

Those are movie quotes. I re-wrote them with help of dictionaries, which are below.

< Will >

> A : Do you plan to save them, even though you know you can't survive while doing that?
>
> B : I do and I promise.

---

< Would >

> A : Do you REALLY want to risk your life for them? You could be killed!
>
> B : I do and I hope so.

So, how close am I?

Comment: You're subtly shifting the context by moving from *even though you **know** [you'll die]* (the "saviour's" death is a certainty) to *You **could** be killed!* (possibly, but it's *not* a certainty). But in neither case does it make sense for the saviour to say *and I hope so* (unless he actually has a death-wish, which is a bit too weird to use in an example context here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  First, minor correction:  "Will" is always future.  Of course, it doesn't mean it *will* necessarily happen, only that it is expected to happen.

> A : You'll die for them?
>
> B : Yes, I will!

A:  You intend to die for them?

B.  Yes, I intend to die for them (hopefully not in vain).

> A : You'd die for them?
>
> B : Yes, I would!

A:  Should the possibility arise, would you die for them?

B:  Yes, should the possibility arise, I would.

Using will implies it is a question of time, not if.  Using would means it is a conditional situation, and that it is not *necessarily* going to be the case.

Putting it in another context:

> A:  You'll do your chores?
>
> B:  Yes, I will!

A: You intend to do your chores?

B: Yes, I intend to do my chores.

> A:  You would do your chores?
>
> B:  Yes, I would!

A: Should I ask you to do your chores, would you do them?

B: Yes, should you ask me to do my chores, I would do them.